# Bootstrap react carousel auto play off

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am new to reactJS and on my page i have multiple carousels. Is there a way that there autoplay is off and do not conflict with other carousels

```
<Carousel>
   <Carousel.Item><img></Carousel.Item>
   <Carousel.Item><img></Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>

<Carousel>
   <Carousel.Item><img></Carousel.Item>
   <Carousel.Item><img></Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>

<Carousel>
   <Carousel.Item><img></Carousel.Item>
   <Carousel.Item><img></Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```

I cant assign IDs to Carousels because they are dynamic

Comment: How exactly should autoplay be managed? Only one carousel at a time? But what should turn autoplay off and on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set `interval` prop of `Carousel` to null for stopping autoplay:

```
<Carousel interval={null}>
   <Carousel.Item><img></Carousel.Item>
   <Carousel.Item><img></Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>

<Carousel  interval={null}>
   <Carousel.Item><img></Carousel.Item>
   <Carousel.Item><img></Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>

<Carousel  interval={null}>
   <Carousel.Item><img></Carousel.Item>
   <Carousel.Item><img></Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```

[image: Edit reactbootstrapcarousel (forked)]